# I can not insert variables from C # to MySql Database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio

I have a database with the infos of the buyers of my product, but I would like it to send the value provided by the program to the database, if it is null, how can I do this?

Code:

I have a database with the infos of the buyers of my product, but I would like it to send the value provided by the program to the database, if it is null, how can I do this?

Code:

```
string comando = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_usuario WHERE user=@Usuario AND pw=@Senha AND tipo=1";
var connection = new MySqlConnection(connString);
var cmd = new MySqlCommand(comando, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", usuario);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Senha", senha);
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
connection.Open();
MySqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (leitor.Read())
{
    hd_id = leitor["id"].ToString();
}
if (hd_id == null)
{
    //Code i need here
}
int retorno = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
connection.Close();
```

Comment: If you want to be able to set a parameter to null then don't use `AddWithValue`. Use `Add` to create the parameter and specify the data type when you do so.  You can then set the `Value` property of that parameter to `DBNull.value` if you don't have an actual value for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite a bit that has been lost in translation in this question, but from I think I am reading I think you want the ID from the database to be retrieved. But the query is just running a `count` command which will not contain that.

```
string comando = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_usuario WHERE user=@Usuario AND pw=@Senha AND tipo=1";
```

should actually be

```
string comando = "SELECT id FROM tbl_usuario WHERE user=@Usuario AND pw=@Senha AND tipo=1";
```

As you are only returning 1 value (or null if no record match) then you do not need to use a reader; and you can read the return directly, and check for null

```
var sqlReturn = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (sqlReturn == null) {  /* Code i need here */ }
else { hd_id = (int)sqlReturn; }
```

If I did not understand the question; please feel free to let me know and we'll see if we can get you fixed up.

Comment: I made a big mess with google translator but you managed to find out exactly what I wanted, thank you.

Comment: I was using count to check if the login and password entered were correct, with this select id, it will also check the same way?

Comment: If the username and password do not match, there will be no value returned; that will be caught by `if (sqlReturn == null) {  /* Code i need here */ }`

Answer (score 0):

**C#**

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", String.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario) ? DBNull.Value : usuario);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Senha", String.IsNullOrEmpty(senha) ? DBNull.Value : senha);
```

Comment: I do not think you understood very well what I wanted.
I would like it to take the primary key (user) and return the value of the id of the person in the database to the hd_id variable.

Comment: Mate, you didnt understand what you asked, then. "I have a database with the infos of the buyers of my product, but I would like it to send the value provided by the program to the database, if it is null, how can I do this?"

Comment: I would suggest you to ask in portuguese, but this is not the right place to do so. Review your question.